# How to browse windows shares from Unity

Tags: nautilus, windows, unity, samba, sharing

How can I browse windows shares from unity?

Comment: This question does not apply to recent versions of Ubuntu. With 11.10, at least through 12.10, you should be able to just click the file-folder icon in the launcher, which opens the Nautilus file browser. Then click "Browse Network" on the sidebar... et voila!

Answer (score 3):

The only way I've found out how to do this is to open a folder window from Unity and then find it from there. Go to Files and Folders on the launcher on the left, and open any folder window (ie, Documents). If it doesn't open in the file manager, hit the little folder icon on the top-right. You should then see the classic file manager appear. Open the **Go** menu and select **Network**. From there you can browse Windows shares.

If you already have the file manager pinned to your launcher, you can also open it there.

So, in short, I don't think you can currently do this from within Unity. Whether this will be a feature for 11.04 remains to be seen.

Comment: Thank you. I think the to-do list for 11.04 Unity is way too extensive to be achievable in only six months.

Comment: The file manager will be in the Launcher by default in 11.04. You'll have a Desktop Folder by default in 11.04 (files on the desktop from ~/Desktop). We will also make some small improvements to file management in the Dash, but that won't be the focus for 11.04.

Comment: Looking at Unity, I really miss the convenience of the old "Places" menu. I was hoping Unity would at least equal it in terms of functionality rather than remove the concept all together.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to connect to a specific thing (network location, ftp, etc...) and want to do it like you used to (Places -> Connect to Server), you can open the file manager (or open any folder to open the file manager) and do File -> Connect to Server